# Mapreduce job failed with IO Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am running a single node hadoop environment. I have a mapreduce job to calculate average of some monitored information for some specific time periods, say hourly average.This job write output to a path within hdfs.It is get cleaned up ech time before running the job. It was working fine for a month. Yesterday , while running job, I got an exception from jobclient, says:

**File /user/root/out1/_temporary/_attempt_201401141113_0007_r_000000_0/hi/130-r-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1**

Full stacktrace is as follows:

```
  ..........

14/01/17 12:00:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 32%
14/01/17 12:00:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 74%
14/01/17 12:00:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401141113_0007_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/root/out1/_temporary/_attempt_201401141113_0007_r_000000_0/hi/130-r-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2829)
```

From the initial search on google, says about storage space issue.But I don't think so, because my whole input data should be less than **600MB** and there is around **1.5GB** free space available on node. I ran **hadoop dfsadmin -report** command and it return as follows:

```
 $hadoop dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 11353194496 (10.57 GB)
Present Capacity: 2354425856 (2.19 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1633726464 (1.52 GB)
DFS Used: 720699392 (687.31 MB)
DFS Used%: 30.61%
Under replicated blocks: 49
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Name: 192.168.1.149:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 11353194496 (10.57 GB)
DFS Used: 720699392 (687.31 MB)
Non DFS Used: 8998768640 (8.38 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1633726464(1.52 GB)
DFS Used%: 6.35%
DFS Remaining%: 14.39%
Last contact: Fri Jan 17 04:36:55 GMT+05:30 2014
```

Please give me a solution.Is this can be a configuration issue. I dont know much about the hadoop configuration.Please help..

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but it seems you are using too many replicas. If you only have one node, your files should only have one replica. This output "Under replicated blocks: 49" indicates that 49 blocks are underreplicated, which is going to be a problem since there are no more nodes available to replicate them to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, maybe, your problem is actually a space problem. You have one replica set, so if your input is 600 mb it will take 1.2 gb on your cluster.

You still have 300mb free that is probably not enough to send the data between nodes.

My advice is to use a smaller dataset to check if this is the problem, of around 300mb or less. Then, if you don't solve it this way, try to set the replicas to 0 on the conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>0</value>
</property>
```